# Smart way to disable instruments in ableton

Tags: ableton-live, workflow

So I found [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/tcdLKrSuYDE) on creating seamless patch transitions in Ableton using the chain selector to change patches.

I am worried about the fact that every Instrument on a track remains active (and continues to use CPU) even when no midi is sent. Is there a way I could set an audio gate as some sort of trigger that turns off my instrument once sound falls below a noise threshold? It would then need to turn it back on once the instrument gets re-selected. This way I get the best of both worlds: seamless transitions + low cpu usage

I tried using the Max4Live `Envelope Follower CV` in inverted mode but then, I don't have any way to re-enable the sound after it gets shut off. I'd need some sort of AND gate (ex: if sound is below threshold AND sound should be off THEN disable the instrument).

Anyways, help would be greatly appreciated :)